# Jenkinsfile inline checkout of a repo using ssh deploy keys possible?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was checking out a repo inline in the Jenkinsfile like the below and installing/running :

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: '../myRepoFolder']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '92312d0c-12301230-12931293-f92124', url: 'https://github.com/MyOrg/my-repo']]])

container('node') {
  dir('../myRepoFolder'){
   //run some command on folder - npm ci, npm start etc...
  }
}
```

This was working fine for a while, but then we switched from using standard authentication with https git url to ssh auth with deploy keys - so the above inline checkout no longer works

I have a Jenkins credential (`deploy-key`) setup with my private key setup w/ `my-repo`. How can I modify the Jenkins `checkout()` command to use ssh to checkout my repo in the same way I have above?

Comment: For ssh checkout I found that the ssh-agent plugin is the right way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSH credentials and SSH URL:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: '../myRepoFolder']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<gitSshCredentials>', url: '<gitRepoSshURL>']]])
```